# ZURB Foundation - can't use column in class name (reserved words)

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Are there **reserved words** in the ZURB Foundation responsive framework? If there are, where are they documented?

I have a table that was built with divs using css (display: table, table-row, and table-cell).

What I get in the view is this...

[image: Table1]

As you can see, the last header has a space between itself and the first row.

I have troubleshot this down to the ZURB Foundation medial queries.

```
@media only screen
[class*="column"] + [class*="column"]:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

**Note:** I have tested this using Chrome (Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit)) only.

Depending on screen size, the space will be below or to the left as the next image displays.

[image: table2]

If I disable the media queries from ZURB, the issue is resolved.

However, media queries is not the root cause of this issue. The problem is that I have a class name that includes the word **column** i.e. column-sea-foam or my-class-name-with-column.

> Other examples that cannot be used as well

```
class="lkjcolumnlkasjdg"
class="large-columns-here"
class="columnz-here"
i.e. any condition where /column/.test( className );
```

If the word **column** is included in any class name for that header, the space is included as you can see by the media query **class*="column"**

I can get around this issue by not using the world **column**, which I find slightly limiting in what I can now use for class names; the price of using a responsive framework I guess.

I had to spend time TS'ing this issue and I would either like to find where ZURB has documented reserved words, or notify ZURB of the issue so that it can be documented.

Comment: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/ it's in the documentation... ... ... ...

Comment: http://sudheerdev.github.io/Foundation5CheatSheet/

Comment: I am still having some trouble finding where reserved words are specifically called out in the either link you have provided.

Comment: What do you mean by where. It's in your foundation's css,  just avoid it. There is nothing to fuss about it.  Really.

Comment: If you know where exactly this is documented in the Zurb docs please provide the text and a link. That would be most helpful to me.